# How do I split large SQL database backup files in .net?

Tags: .net, sql, backup, restore

I am working on backing up and restoration of SQL Database. I am new to this.I have an issue related to Backup process. I have **SQL database** and I am using **BACKUP** and **RESTORE** classes to perform backup and restore of database.

I want to make my program more efficient using **split backup**. I have aprx 15 to 20 GB of data. so I want to split my my backup files in specified limit lets say 8-10 GB. I can do this using below SQL statements:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks
TO  DISK = 'C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks1.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks2.bak',
    DISK = 'C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks3.bak'
GO
```

But I want to do this by using  **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup** classes. And I want to get the size of my backup files. Because my criteria is to split file if my database size exceeds 10 GB otherwise it will not split my file. SO my issue is how can I get size of my database when taking backup.

Comment: Do you have existing code that is working with the `Backup` class? If so, can you show it please?

Answer (score 1):

If your original query works like you said it does (I don't know off the top of my head if it works that way or not) you just need to add the additional devices to the `Backup` object

This should be the equivalent SMO code

```
var server = new Server(/*...*/);
var backup = new Backup();

backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
backup.Database = "AdventureWorks";

backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks1.bak",DeviceType.File);
backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks2.bak",DeviceType.File);
backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Backup\MultiFile\AdventureWorks3.bak",DeviceType.File);

backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott For your quick response. I haven't tried this one. But I think this will work. But Sorry I forgot to write another issue.Let me tell you other case. I want to split my backup files if size of my database exceeds specific limit of 10 GB. So My issue is How Can I get actual size of my backup files? Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: That I do not know, I never have needed to split backup files before. I only knew how to do the direct translation of what you posted in SQL to C# syntax using SMO.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your kind consideration. So is there no any other way to get actual size of my backup files before I code for Backup..?

Comment: As I said; there may, or may not, be a easy way to do that. I just don't know enough about splitting backups to be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [`BlockSize`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.blocksize.aspx) on the `Backup` object?

```
var server = new Server();
var backup = new Backup { BlockSize = 1073741824 };

// other settings

backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. No I haven't tried it as I have mentioned I am new to this. I am currently working on that and I will reply whatever happens.

Comment: I don't think BlockSize does what you think it does, From the msdn "*The supported sizes are 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, and 65536 (64 KB) bytes. The default is 65536 for tape devices and 512 otherwise. Backup automatically selects the default for the device.*"